# Swapping out an image within a span in jQuery

Tags: jquery

so I am doing a dropdown list:

```
<section class="services-list">



<a><h3>Extension Building</h3><span></span></a><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique     senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat     vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper.     Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

<a><h3>Conversion Specialising</h3><span></span></a><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi     tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam,     feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas     semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

</section>
```

The paragraph is display:none and is made visible once the a tag is clicked. I have this working OK so only the next paragraph is shown and not all of them. However I also have a down arrow in the span tag to show something drops down if clicked. I rotate that span in css using a class of .minimise, so what I want is for the class to be added to the specific span when the a tag is clicked so the arrow points upwards to show the p can be hidden again. I have got as far as toggling the class in jQuery, but it toggles the class on ALL the spans rather than in the specific a tag.

Here is my current jQuery:

```
 $(".services-list a").click(function(){
        $(this).next('services-list a span').toggleClass("minimise");
        $(this).next("p").stop('true','true').slideToggle("fast");

    });
```

Hope that all made sense! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The `span` you want to target is a descendant of the clicked `a` element so use `.find()`

```
$(".services-list a").click(function () {
    $(this).find('span').toggleClass("minimise");
    $(this).next("p").stop(true, true).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7eq3Z/)